# pivot report in oracle apex to show total per row and columns

Tags: oracle, pivot, oracle-apex

**I have this view**

name.......task........Sub total

George...Leave.......50

Mason....Sick.........100

George...Sick..........20

Mike......Vacation.....40

How can I have it presented like this in oracle apex? I've tried the pivot option in apex but I only can get the total per column NOT per row!! any idea is greatly appreciated. please keep in mind that the task can be anything.

```
     ....Leave    Sick    Vacation......etc...total
```

George......50...........20............0.............................70

Mason.......0..........100.............0.............................100

Mike...........0..........0...............40.............................40

total..........50.........120.............40

Answer (score 0):

Did you try an Interactive Report? That function is included on it.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEEUG/managing-pivot-reports.htm#GUID-B71B947D-FC08-466C-9739-DFFE7981F4E8

[image]

Comment: I already have the pivot report with total per column. my problem is getting the total per row.

Comment: Ok, then you have to create the query pivot.  https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/pivot.php

Comment: But how can I do that when the "Tasks" can be anything(dynamic)? do you have an email I can talk to you? I really appreciate your help and I am willing to pay for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grouping set to get the total values or you can use a union all as well.

union all example:

```
select name, task, subtotal 
from my_view
union all
select name, 'Grand Total' task, sum(subtotal) subtotal  
from my_view 
group by name,task
```

Grouping set example:

```
select name, nvl(task, 'Grand Total') task, sum(subtotal) subtotal 
from(select * from my_view)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((name,task,subtotal),(name))
```

I think grouping set has a much better performance but I am not exactly sure. You mentioned in your post you have already used the pivot function in the interactive report so I'll leave it to you to figure out how that piece works.